# Searching for specific duplicate ID's

Tags: perl, duplicates

I've written a perl script which reads in 2 different files, compares the ID's in these two files and only prints out the data where the ID's match. The ID file is read into an array, while the data file is read line by line. This all works rather well, however now I need to add more to it. In my data file, I'll sometimes have rows where the ID is duplicated, as the subject has been for more than one visit to give samples. I therefore need to look for these duplicates and take only the latest date of visit.

So my data file looks something like this:

```
   ID  DOV  Data1  Data2 etc etc
```

Now I've seen hashes are the way to search for duplicates, however all the fixes I've seen have been to simply remove the duplicates indiscriminately, which isn't what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read all lines into a hash by ID, overwriting any previous value.  If the input is not sorted by DOV, you need to add a comparison and only replace if the new value is newer.  Then at the end print out the hash.  (Assuming "DOV" stands for "date of visit".)

Comment: @tripleee Do you mean read the entire file into a hash in one go or read it in line by line? I've never worked with hashes so if you could give an example of what you mean that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# read id file
my %id_hash;
while (<IDFILE>) {
  chomp;
  $id_hash{$_} = 1;
}

#read data file
while (<DATAFILE>) {
  my @arr = split(/\s+/, $_);
  if (defined $id_hash{$arr[0]}) { # only process if exists in id file
    # and only if this is the first data entry or a later visit
    if ( (not ref $id_hash{$arr[0]}) or ($id_hash{$arr[0]}[1] < $arr[1]) ) {
      # store all data in an array ref
      $id_hash{$arr[0]} = [ @arr ];
    }
  }
}

for my $id (keys %id_hash) {
  print join(" ", @{$id_hash{$id}}), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You explained it well and you actually managed to do what I had done in my original script with a lot less code! it's a learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

This will show the last DOV for each ID, making a *lot* of assumptions about the input data, so there's a good chance that it won't work out-of-the-box for you.  (In particular, if your input data isn't sorted by date, it won't work at all because it just takes the last date seen for each ID.  Also, if dates are formatted in a way that includes spaces, such as "Mon Jul  9 15:51:22 CEST 2012", it will only get the date up to the first space ("Mon" in this example).)  The point here is just to demonstrate the basic technique, not to provide a full solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;

my %visit;
while (<DATA>) {
  my ($id, $date) = split;
  $visit{$id} = $date;
} 

for my $id (sort keys %visit) {
  print "$id => $visit{$id}\n";
} 

__DATA__
1       2012-01-01
2       2012-01-02
1       2012-02-03
3       2012-02-04
2       2012-03-05
3       2012-03-06
4       2012-04-07
1       2012-04-08
5       2012-05-09
1       2012-05-10
```